# How to get today date data and yesterday if the fields are filled with now() means both time date is in field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to get today date data and yesterday if the fields are filled with now() means both time date is in the field using MYSQL query?

Can we use Mysql function in like '%curdate()%'?

Comment: You could compare by using mysql day(), month() and year() function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `CURDATE()` function can be used.

```
SELECT required_columns from table_name where date_column = CURDATE() OR date_column = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

OR

```
SELECT required_columns from table_name where date_column between CURDATE() AND date_column = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```